# Java RADIUS Client Libraries

Tags: library, java

I'm interested in what **Java [RADIUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radius) client libraries** are available and actively supported.

This question is similar to [What (good) Java RADIUS server libraries are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217/what-good-java-radius-server-libraries-are-out-there); however, I'm interested in Java RADIUS *client* libraries, as opposed to *server* libraries.

There are a number of *server* libraries, client libraries not written in *Java*, and *immature/incomplete* libraries and forks, so the only *potential* candidates I've encountered so far are the following:

- **[AXL RADIUS Client API](http://www.axlradius.com/RadiusClient.htm)** - Not free/open source
- **[JRadius](http://www.coova.org/JRadius)** - Doesn't appear to be actively maintained, last release January 2011, minimal community activity
- **[JRadiusClient](http://jradius-client.sourceforge.net/)** - Minimal documentation/support, last updated 2004
- **[TinyRadius](http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/)** - Doesn't appear to be actively maintained, last release February 2010, minimal community activity

Are there other libraries missing from my list?

I'd also be interested to know if anyone is actively consuming any of the libraries from the above list or has any experience/recommendations.

Comment: JRadiusClient it is. It seems to have good API, but yes, it is too old so worried to use it in the new project.

Comment: JRadius from coova seems to be a better one. Last updated on 2015, but as long as it satisfies the RFC, it is perfect. https://github.com/coova/jradius/releases/tag/jradius-1.1.5

Comment: To include my feedback, After working on JRadius, it seems very good and customizable. I am currently using it.

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays tinyradius is up to date (2020), specially its netty based fork.

Here is the official tinyradius library and two of its other forks (including the netty one):

**tinyradius-netty** (tinyradius fork using Java 8 Netty's features) ([github](https://github.com/globalreachtech/tinyradius-netty), [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.globalreachtech/tinyradius-netty/1.4.12)) (last updated on 2020)

**tinyradius** ([github](https://github.com/ctran/TinyRadius), [webpage](http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/), [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tinyradius/tinyradius)) (last updated on 2018)

**tinyradius fork by hynnet** ([maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hynnet/tinyradius)) (last updated on 2016)

Here is a [tutorial for tinyradius fork by hynnet](https://blog.pavelsklenar.com/spring-security-radius-login/) if you are working with Radius and Spring Boot.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm updating the answer, thank you for the feedback. Looks like tinyradius is worth giving a try.